# Is it possible to un-cancel a promise?

Tags: promise, bluebird

If I use the following to trap form validation errors and prevent the rest of the promise chain from running...

```
p.then(() => { if (!this.isValid()) { p.cancel(); }});
```

Is it possible to keep the promise 'alive' such that the next form submission will run the chain again as though it was the first time?

Comment: No, that's what things like observables are for.

Comment: oh. Well they seem kind of similar anyhow.

Comment: Once a promise settles by resolving or rejecting (cancel is just syntactic sugar for rejecting using a cancellation token), its state is final, it cannot be "un-settled".

Comment: Each form submission should create an independent promise chain. Two consecutive form submissions are not a causal chain of events, so they shouldn't be encapsulated by a single promise chain.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Instead, I have the code that runs the validation supply the validation function as a parameter to the code that resolves the promise chain, which it will only do if the validation function returns true.

Comment: @IanWarburton that sounds like the core of your problem then. Create a new question (or update this one) with that bit of code and tell us where you are stuck

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*the next form submission will run the chain again*". The next form submission should create its own chain by calling the functions itself and creating new promises. You cannot "re-run" a promise - a promise represents a result, not a task. Please post your whole code so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Make a new promise each time you submit the form.  Promises are one-shot devices.